# verify(sessionRegistry, times(1)).getAllSessions(principle, true) is returning null

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

```
        List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principle, true);
        verify(sessionRegistry, times(1)).getAllSessions(principle, true).forEach(SessionInformation::expireNow);
```

First line is always is returning empty list which is expected but whenever I'm calling via Mockito.verify then it's returning null.

Comment: I guess it is normal behavior because you mock sessionregistry and you don't use mockito.when for returning result also verify is wrong you try to verify  getAllSessions

Comment: I've already added below following lines but problem remains same;         
                                                                                                 
List<SessionInformation> sessions = Collections.singletonList(new SessionInformation(principle, username, new Date()));
        when(sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principle, true)).thenReturn(sessions);

Answer (score 0):

Verify does not work that way. There is no point to return nor to check value that you provide as a mock value when verify checks if method is called. So why should it return it?

For example if you have declared `sessions` and stub some method like `getAllSessions` to return it. Why would you like to check what it is through verify? It does only verification that some stubbed method is called on a mock.

If you need to use `sessions` for some reason use it directly. Not through verify.

Again: you **stub** the method on your mock you do not **test** that method but other methods that use that stubbed method. That is the whole point of mocking and stubbing. You should trust that Mockito does what it promises and lets the code use stubbed method as you have configured.